# Validating if the word "the" is inside of my string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, for-loop

I am trying to find how many times the word "the" appears in a sentence that a user created while using a for loop. My problem is, inside of the loop, I am creating an if statement to test it but I don't know what to put inside of the if statement.. Everything I've tried that I have seen on this site is giving me errors.

Comment: Show the try that you felt was the most promising, along with the error you got.

Comment: We cant debug a story... for future reference.

Answer (score -2):

- Use the string **.Split** method to get a array of strings.
- **Foreach** string in the array

  - If the string matches the predifined value, increment the counter.